# Java Fork/Join Pool with priority queue?

Tags: java, priority-queue, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I need to process many PDF-Files. So I have a list of files (files that are in some folder or zip file). I want a subtask per PDF. Then I create a subtask per page, so it can be processed.

I was thinking of using a fork/join pool but that just keeps creating more subtasks to read more files and I run out of memory.
Sometimes I get many small files, sometimes I get large files with many pages. It makes no sense loading more documents when there are already many pages queued up to be processed.

1. Each pdf file from a folder is read and a subtask (2) is created, forked, and joined.
2. For each page a subtask (3) is created, forked, and joined.
3. Process this page.

There's `ForkJoinTask.helpQuiesce()`, which might be good enough in some situations. I can just call `ForkJoinTask.helpQuiesce()` after creating some subtasks. This way the subtasks are more likely to be processed before more data is loaded.

But I can't find anything to set the priority of a subtask. Wouldn't that be a lot easier? If I understand the documentation correctly, there is one *submission queue* and then one *task queue* per worker thread. Is there no way to control which tasks from the submission queue are processed first? I can pass a factory for the worker threads, but not for the submission queue.

Like in the divide-and-conquer metaphor: It might make more sense to plunder all cities before you invade a new country or even a new continent, so you get enough resources needed for those tasks. But how is this controlled?

I know Fork/Join uses work stealing and you usually don't have to bother. But I need to build a batch processing tool and I can't have it just load gigabytes of data to memory before it even begins processing any of the pages. But I don't need some framework like hadoop for a bunch of pdf files. That would be overkill.

I could use a `PriorityQueue<E>`, but that seems to be a lot more work as this is only a simple data structure, while Fork/Join is a framework.

Is there no way of controlling the order in which tasks are processed? What am I missing? Is there some other priority queue based solution available in Java?

Comment: Does this help you: https://www.baeldung.com/java-priority-job-schedule ?

Comment: Can you not submit tasks to the fork join pool according to your required batch size, wait for its completion, before submitting the next batch?

Comment: @Prasanna Sure. I could use `helpQuiesce()`. I just don't understand why this framework doesn't have a priority queue.