# How to make threads execute in the order they are created in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, java-threads

I am using a niche database. It currently does not support the export of sql files in terms of data backup, only dump files, but the demand needs to export sql files, so I can only query them by myself and write them into the sql file.

Because the code is commercial, so I abstract the code, which causes inconvenience, please forgive me.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadQueryWrite {

    @AllArgsConstructor
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        /**
         * database tableName
         */
        String tableName;
        /**
         * The starting primary key of the query range
         */
        long startId;
        /**
         * The ending primary key of the query range
         */
        long endId;

        /**
         * File writing character stream
         */
        Writer writer;



        @Override
        public void run() {
            doQuery();

        }

        private void doQuery() {
            // resultSet = select * from tableName where id between startId and endId;
            // doWriteFile(resultSet);
        }

        private void doWriteFile(ResultSet resultSet) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
            try {
                while(resultSet.next()){
                    // sb.append()
                }
                synchronized(writer){
                    writer.write(sb.toString());
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Assuming that the number of rows of database data
        // has been obtained is 10000000 rows
        int count = 10000000;
        String tableName = "test_table";
        String filePath = "c:\\test\\test.sql";
        ThreadQueryWrite queryWrite = new ThreadQueryWrite();
        queryWrite.doExportSql(count, tableName, filePath);
    }

    private void doExportSql(int count, String tableName, String filePath) throws IOException {
        int maxQueryCount = 3000;

        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
                Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(filePath)),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i += maxQueryCount) {
            MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(tableName, i, i + maxQueryCount - 1, writer);
            threadPoolExecutor.submit(myRunnable);
        }
        threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Because some tables have a large amount of data, I want to save as much time as possible, so I use multi-threading. Each thread divides a range according to the primary key and performs asynchronous queries.

I want to ensure that the primary key id is continuous when writing to the file, from 1 to 10000000.

```sql
insert into table(id) values
    (1),
    ......,
    (3000);
insert into table(id) values
    (3001),
    ......,
    (6000);
......
```

However, I perform a segmented query based on the primary key id, and there is no guarantee which thread will execute the query first. This may cause the id range to be 3001~6000 at the beginning of the file, and the id to be 1~3000 at the end, as follows,

```
insert into table(id) values
    (3001),
    ......,
    (6000);
insert into table(id) values
    (1),
    ......,
    (3000);
......
```

I have tried this method[Ordering threads to run in the order they were created/started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741765/ordering-threads-to-run-in-the-order-they-were-created-started)

But this may bring a lot of memory pressure, because I load all the query data into the memory, and then process the callback results of the threads one by one to write the SQL file.

I hope that the primary key id in the sql file is in order, according to the order of self-increment in the database.

There is currently no solution, any reply would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can multiple threads write data into a file at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602466/can-multiple-threads-write-data-into-a-file-at-the-same-time)

Comment: It sounds like you really want something that runs sequentially instead of in parallel :) Have you considered letting it write randomly to the file, and then sorting the file by primary key afterwards?

Comment: I think, instead, you want to look towards a "producer/consumer" concept - so you have multi threads "producing" output and a (single in this case) "consumer" which is consuming that content. The consumer can then make decisions about how to process the results.  You could also run all the threads and have them write to individual files and when they are all completed, combine those files into one

Comment: There are lots of different approaches one could take to this problem domain, but your proposed solution almost feels like [mapreduce](https://www.ibm.com/topics/mapreduce) (not that there's anything wrong with that).

Comment: Why not just have each thread write to a separate file?  If absolutely necessary you could cat the files afterwards, but if they are just going to be played back in order can you just leave them separate?

Comment: When dumping all of the data, does it really make sense to have it sorted on query or before writing just so you can import it in order into another system? Why bother about sorting at all?

Comment: Consider this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73723475/4222206

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't determine the size of the exported file. If the offset is designed according to the number of lines, but I will have other information before this, the number of lines is uncertain.@experimentunit1998X

Comment: Thanks for the help, this seems like a good approach, I decided to write each thread to the file individually and finally write to a final file in file order.@TheNytangel

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally decided to go with this solution.@MadProgrammer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally decided to go with this solution. I separated them to speed up file export.@Yaytay

Comment: Thanks for the help, it doesn't seem to solve my problem, but it taught me something I didn't know.
Some of our business scenarios rely on this sorting, such as the stored motion coordinate data of the car, which is generated and inserted into the database according to the time and the primary key is auto-incremented. If it is not in the order, we need to sort the query results, but we want to avoid Because of the time overhead caused by sorting.
The separate query is to speed up the sql file export time. @Queeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could enforce encountered order at terminal operation and do intermediate operations in parallel using streams `parallel` and `foreachOrdered` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336825/benefit-of-using-foreachordered-with-parallel-streams) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216588/how-to-ensure-order-of-processing-in-java8-streams)
Did not [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500925/java-fork-join-pool-with-priority-queue) anything which could change the forkjoin pool queue to priority queue to use startId to decide priority.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ThreadQueryWrite {

    @AllArgsConstructor
    class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

        /**
         * database tableName
         */
        String tableName;
        /**
         * The starting primary key of the query range
         */
        long startId;

        public long getStartId() {
            return startId;
        }

        /**
         * The ending primary key of the query range
         */
        long endId;

        /**
         * File writing character stream
         */
        Writer writer;



        @Override
        public void run() {
            doQuery();

        }

        private void doQuery() {
            // resultSet = select * from tableName where id between startId and endId;
            // doWriteFile(resultSet);
        }

        public StringBuilder queryAndGetResult() {
            System.out.println(startId+" Querying for startId ");
            // resultSet = select * from tableName where id between startId and endId;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""+startId);
            try {
               // while(resultSet.next()){
                    // sb.append()
                //}

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println(startId+" Query Result ");

            return sb;
        }



        private void doWriteFile(ResultSet resultSet) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
            try {
                while(resultSet.next()){
                    // sb.append()
                }
                synchronized(writer){
                    writer.write(sb.toString());
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Assuming that the number of rows of database data
        // has been obtained is 10000000 rows
        int count = 100;
        String tableName = "test_table";
        String filePath = "c:\\test\\test.sql";
        ThreadQueryWrite queryWrite = new ThreadQueryWrite();
        queryWrite.doExportSql(count, tableName, filePath);
    }

    private void doExportSql(int count, String tableName, String filePath) throws IOException {
        int maxQueryCount = 3;//for increasing readibility of output

        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(filePath)),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ArrayList<MyRunnable> myRunnables = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i += maxQueryCount) {
            MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(tableName, i, i + maxQueryCount - 1, writer);
            myRunnables.add(myRunnable);
        }

        myRunnables.stream()
                .parallel()
                .map(myRunnable -> myRunnable.queryAndGetResult())
                .forEachOrdered(resultSetString-> writeToFile(writer, resultSetString));


    }

    private static void writeToFile(Writer writer, StringBuilder resultSetString) {
        try {
            System.out.println(resultSetString+" File out");
            writer.write(resultSetString.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I have a question. If this method is used, will the data in the database be accumulated in the memory at the same time? I want to reduce the pressure on the memory.

Comment: Yes,it might hold half of the data.Wanted to use priority queue so that the first half gets processsed and pushed to file but as of now no such implementation is available where we could use that.

Comment: One more approach (do not have much knowledge on it ) could be writing custom splititerator so that first half gets processed first so that memory usage is low.

Comment: Should raise a different question to address this approach.

Comment: I conducted a test using 10,000,000 pieces of data, and each thread wrote a separate file and then integrated it. The event efficiency was too poor, and the memory growth did not make much difference. It does seem to be a feasible solution at present.